# Xcode have 2 projects under 1 workspace

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, workspace, uiviewcontentmode

I have 1 workspace with project with project with swift3.
Now I need to add other project or target. I am not sure.
But the goal is to have the other project in swift4. It will be helper project for main project in swift3. And this second project should be available from swift3. It's extensions for UIViewController. How can I make it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that either as separate project or as target of existing project.

1. Create Framework

[image]

2. Choose Swift version(4.0 in your case)

[image]

3. Add Swift file

[image]

4. Link framework in application

[image]

5. Import framework and use extension

[image]